# Valgrind in Qt Creator

Tags: qt-creator

Using the Memcheck function of Qt Creator returns the following:

```
valgrind: Bad option: --xml=yes, but no XML destination specified
valgrind: --xml=yes has been specified, but there is no XML output
valgrind: destination.  You must specify an XML output destination
valgrind: using --xml-fd, --xml-file or --xml-socket.
valgrind: Use --help for more information or consult the user manual.
Analyzing finished.
** Unknown error **
```

Is there something in the configuration that hasn't been set properly, or is this a Qt Creator bug? I can't see anywhere in the settings where I could possibly inject a command line argument or set the XML file output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's due a [xml-socket bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382998) in valgrind-3.13.

For now, you can downgrade to valgrind-3.12 if you want to use valgrind without any problems.

Comment: You can easely downgrade using your package manager (downgrade for instance in archlinux)


I think 3.4 may be ok if you must

Comment: I'm not root on the server, I used 3.11 from http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.9/general/valgrind.html. Thanks