# How to use Valgrind with Qt Creator to debug a remote application?

Tags: c++, qt, valgrind

I have a c++ app that I am developing in Qt Creator (Qt Creator 4.7.0, Qt version 5.2.1). The app runs on a beaglebone (debian). I am debugging the app using Qt Creator's remote debugging.

The app has some memory issues, so I am trying to use Valgrind to diagnose them. Whenever I start a Memcheck analysis from Qt Creator, all it outputs is:

> 16:22:58: /usr/local/bin/valgrind --child-silent-after-fork=yes --xml-socket=10.0.2.15:38409 --log-socket=10.0.2.15:43999 --xml=yes --smc-check=all --tool=memcheck --gen-suppressions=all --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full --num-callers=25 --vgdb=yes --vgdb-error=0 /home/debian/MyApp
>
> ==28159== Failed to connect to logging server '10.0.2.15:37567'.
>
> ==28159== Logging messages will be sent to stderr instead.
>
> ==28159== Failed to connect to XML logging server '10.0.2.15:39405'.
>
> ==28159== XML output will be sent to stderr instead.
>
> valgrind: m_libcprint.c:384 (prepare_sink_socket): Assertion 'sink->fd
> == 2' failed.
>
> 16:27:13: Analyzing finished.

To address the first two errors, I would like to change the call to valgrind to make the logging write to a file instead. However, I cannot find where to change the call that Qt Creator makes to valgrind. Tools->Options->Analyzer->Valgrind doesn't seem to allow me to change the logging behavior.

I have no idea what is causing the last error. Qt documentation makes it seem like all I should have to do is press go and it should work.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you run valgrind for, say, /bin/ls, from beaglebone command line?

Comment: As for assert, check the source, ideally add github (or what ever) link to the line in the question. Why does fd need to be 2? It might be related to the other errors.

Comment: Oh, and I presume that 10.0.2.15 is your PC? Are you sure there's no firewall or something? You could test with netcat/telnet.

Comment: @hyde valgrind works properly from the beaglebone via ssh, but when I use it on the beaglebone I don't attempt to redirect the logging output. I have a sneaking suspicion that it fails in Qt because of the way its trying to log, but I don't see where to change it. And yes 10.0.2.15 is my PC, which is an ubuntu virtual box

Comment: @hyde as for the assert, my best guess that after failing to log to the network socket it tries to log to a file descriptor is if I had specified --log-fd=2 in the valgrind call, but I really don't know. I have no idea why it needs to be 2, I guess I'll look through the valgrind source

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531851/valgrind-in-qt-creator) question have an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the options `xml-socket`, `log-socket` and `xml=yes` worked for me.  It removed the warnings and resolved the assertion.

Comment: How did you remove these options for QtCreator?

Comment: I guess I ran valgrind from the command line, not from within QtCreator.